# Stuck with The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello im stuck with this ? anybody has the fix ? trying to bring back up data from an other table with a search button

```
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0; 
function Search(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Task");

var str = formS.getRange("C3").getValue();
var values =  ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 var row = values[i];
 if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX]== str) {

  formS.getRange("C6").setValues(row[0]);
  formS.getRange("C8").setValues(row[1]);
  formS.getRange("C10").setValues(row[2]);
  formS.getRange("E6").setValues(row[3]);
  formS.getRange("E8").setValues(row[4]);
  formS.getRange("E10").setValues(row[5]);

   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using a value for example row[0].  So you should be using `setValue(row[0])` not `setValues(row[0])`.  `setValues` expects a 2D array as its parameter.

Comment: LMFAO, thanks you so much i feel like an idiot